# How to install msmtpd on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, server, package-management, email, smtp

I'm able to install `msmtp` just find on Ubuntu 18.04 with: `apt install msmtp msmtp-mta ca-certificates`, however I'm not finding [`Minimal SMTP server (msmtpd)`](https://marlam.de/msmtp/msmtp.html#Minimal-SMTP-server-_0028msmtpd_0029) anywhere on the filesystem. It also does not appear to be available within `apt search`

How can I install this service on Ubuntu 180.04 servers?

Comment: Take a look at the clamsmtp package, it contains /usr/sbin/clamsmtpd which might meet your needs.

Comment: @ubfan1 `clamsmtpd` is for scanning emails for viruses (https://manpages.debian.org/testing/clamsmtp/clamsmtpd.8.en.html)...

Comment: See the second line of the package description: It can act as a traditional SMTP proxy with publicly  accessible ports or as a transparent proxy, where SMTP traffic is redirected  to the ClamSMTP by your router.  Is a traditional SMTP proxy what you need?

Comment: `dpkg -l msmtp msmtp-mta ca-certificates ;for i in msmtp msmtp-mta ca-certificates ; do dpkg -L $i; done` will tell you about the package contents.

Comment: @waltinator thanks, I did a search with `apt-file` and then after looking closer at the package's version info `apt show`, it is quite outdated and `msmtpd` is simply missing everywhere, so I believe I must resort to building it from scratch and [thus asked this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182472/how-to-compile-msmtp-from-source-install-in-the-proper-location-and-install-a-s).