# How to compile msmtp from source, install in the proper location and install a service startup script for 18.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, compiling

I've found that the `msmtp` package for Ubuntu 18.04 is old and missing a component. The current included package is version [1.6.6 from 2016-11-14](https://marlam.de/msmtp/download/) and is missing `msmtpd`.  I would like to install version [1.8.6 from 2019-09-27](https://marlam.de/msmtp/releases/msmtp-1.8.6.tar.xz) that is significantly updated and does include `msmtpd`.

What are the proper configuration arguments that would get this to compile with appropriate `make install` locations for Ubuntu 18.04?

Additionally, what would be the process for creating a quick `/etc/init.d/` startup script for this so as to make sure that this service starts at boot-up and can be restarted easily?

A simle `./configure` gives the following output, which appears to be missing TLS and I don't think /usr/local is the preferred folder from the other package's defaults:

```
Install prefix ......... : /usr/local
NLS support ............ : yes
TLS support ............ : no (Library: none)
IDN support ............ : yes (no library required)
GNU SASL support ....... : no (most likely unnecessary)
Libsecret support (GNOME): no
MacOS X Keychain support : no
Build msmtpd ............: yes
```

Answer (score 3):

First, `/usr/local` is usually where manually installed packages go (`/usr/local/bin`). This will override any packages in `/usr/bin` or other directories used by `apt` installed packages.

Next, install the build dependencies:

```
sudo apt build-dep msmtp
```

Now, `cd` into the msmtp directory and run the following commands:

```
make clean
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

---

This will install to the correct location which is `/usr/local`. When you install to this directory, you do not need to uninstall the `apt` version so that packages that depend on `msmtp` will not break. When you or the system runs `msmtp`, the version in `/usr/local` will be used.

To uninstall, `cd` into the msmtp directory and run the following command:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Comment: I assume the `apt build-dep msmtp` is to get the TLS support from the original package? When I execute this I get `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: @ylluminate Yes, this installs all the packages needed to build msmtp. Try running again. It looks like you ran: `sudo apt build-dep` instead of `sudo apt build-dep msmtp`

Comment: Unfortunately not: https://share.getcloudapp.com/2NuA0XNp

Comment: @ylluminate Sorry, I was looking at a different error message. You need to enable the sources in your /etc/apt/sources.list file. You can easily do that using the software center. https://askubuntu.com/a/857433/167115 Of course, you will probably need to run: `sudo apt update` before you try again.

Comment: Excellent, yes that makes sense and that did work out here now. One final point as per the initial question is the missing aspect of adding the appropriate startup script to `/etc/init.d`. I assume I should just take an existing script and hack it out to work for `msmtpd`, however I do want to be sure I get a clean and appropriate enough starting point.

Comment: @ylluminate Yeah msmtpd just has start stop options and I don't see any systemd stuff so that sounds about right. Archlinux has some information but it mentions using a cron service that is not used by Ubuntu and the Ubuntu docs don't say much. There is also a doc directory in the build directory that has an msmtpd file but it doesn't say much either.